# Multipart form: How to send and get parameters in an hidden input in JSP

Tags: jsp, input, hidden, multipartform-data

I have a multipart form with a few fields which values I need to send to a jsp file.

This is the multipart form and this is how I send the parameters (in non multipart, it works perfectly)

```
<div class="createform">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="create" action="createcompetition.jsp" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Competition Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="img">Picture</label>
                    <input type="file" name="img" id ="img" multiple>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="startdate">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
                    <input type="date" id="deadline" name="deadline">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="website">Website URL</label>
                    <input type="url" id="website" name="website">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="termsnconds">Terms &amp; Conds</label>
                    <textarea id="termsnconds" name="termsnconds" cols="28" rows="5" ></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create">
                    <input type="hidden" name="competiname" id="competiname" value="document.getElementById('name').value;" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="competistartdate" id="competistartdate" value="document.getElementById('startdate').value;" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="competideadline" id="competideadline" value="document.getElementById('deadline').value;" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="competiwebsite" id="competiwebsite" value="document.getElementById('website').value;" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="competitermsnconds" id="competitermsnconds" value="document.getElementById('termsnconds').value;" />
                </li>
            </ul>


        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the JSP page which has to receive those parameters to use them in the second `INSERT INTO`.

```
<%
        //Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        //Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
        ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        factory.setRepository(repository);

        //Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        //Parse the request
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = iter.next();

            if (item.isFormField()) {
                //rocessFormField(item);
            } else {
                item.write(new File("C:\\indigo\\eclipse\\workspace\\JSPyDB\\WebContent\\images\\competitions\\salida.png"));
            }
        }
        //File.createTempFile(arg0, arg1)
    %>

    <sql:transaction dataSource="jdbc/PuzzleDB">
        <sql:update>
            INSERT INTO picture_competition (name, url) VALUES (?, ?)
            <sql:param value="salida.png" />
            <sql:param value="/competitions/" />                
        </sql:update>
        <sql:query var="pictures">
            SELECT id FROM picture_competition WHERE name=? 
            <sql:param value="salida.png" />
        </sql:query>
        <c:if test="${!empty pictures.rows}">
            OK
            <c:forEach var="picture" items="${pictures.rows}">
                <sql:update>
                    INSERT INTO Competition (name, id_picture, id_sponsor, start_date, deadline, websiteURL, termsnconds) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
                    <sql:param value="${param.competiname}" />
                    <sql:param value="${picture.id}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${sessionScope.userid}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${param.competistartdate}" />
                    <sql:param value="${param.competideadline}" />
                    <sql:param value="${param.competiwebsite}" />
                    <sql:param value="${param.competitermsnconds}" />
                </sql:update>   
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if> 
    </sql:transaction>
```

But the parameter `${param.name}` is `null`, along with the rest of the parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use the apache commons fileupload lib to get ALL the parameters, not just the file. You can't mix in `request.getParameter` and `${param.competitermsnconds}` because of the fact that you're using `multipart/form-data`...if you try to get the parameter like normal it will be `null` because you can only get it with the fileupload library or `request.getPart` if you're on servlet API 3.0

Comment: And you really ought to make this a servlet anyway. You should not do database updates in jsp.

Comment: thanks develioerwjk, i know that it is better to make servlet out of this but i must do it in version below 3.0

Comment: Below 3.0, do a servlet that uses apache commons fileupload all the way through.  i.e. `if (item.isFormField()) {` there's your non-file fields right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, and now it works perfectly.

Apparently when i did `upload.parseRequest`, all the parameters of the `multipart-form` where inside but i was only getting the uploaded file.

In order to get the rest of the parameters, i had to, 1st, insert them into an `Iterator` object and after, get every one of them by the previously given name in the form.

```
<%
    String name = null ;
    String startdate = null;
    String deadline = null;
    String website = null;
    String termsnconds = null;
    //Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    //Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
    ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
    factory.setRepository(repository);
    //Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    //Parse the request
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = iter.next();
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            InputStream input = item.getInputStream();
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("name")){
                byte[] str = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(str);
                name = new String(str,"UTF8");
            }
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("startdate")){
                byte[] str = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(str);
                startdate = new String(str,"UTF8");
            }
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("deadline")){
                byte[] str = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(str);
                deadline = new String(str,"UTF8");
            }
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("website")){
                byte[] str = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(str);
                website = new String(str,"UTF8");
            }
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("termsnconds")){
                byte[] str = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(str);
                termsnconds = new String(str,"UTF8");
            }
        } else {
                item.write(new File("C:\\indigo\\eclipse\\workspace\\JSPyDB\\WebContent\\images\\competitions\\salida.png"));
        }
    }
        //File.createTempFile(arg0, arg1)


    %>
    <sql:transaction dataSource="jdbc/PuzzleDB">
        <sql:update>
            INSERT INTO picture_competition (name, url) VALUES (?, ?)
            <sql:param value="salida.png" />
            <sql:param value="/competitions/" />                
        </sql:update>
        <sql:query var="pictures">
            SELECT id FROM picture_competition WHERE name=? 
            <sql:param value="salida.png" />
        </sql:query>
        <c:if test="${!empty pictures.rows}">
            <c:forEach var="picture" items="${pictures.rows}">
                <c:set var="competiname" value="<%= name %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competistartdate" value="<%= startdate %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competideadline" value="<%= deadline %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competiwebsite" value="<%= website %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competitermsnconds" value="<%= termsnconds %>"></c:set>
                <sql:update>
                    INSERT INTO Competition (name, id_picture, id_sponsor, start_date, deadline, websiteURL, termsnconds) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
                    <sql:param value="${competiname}" />
                    <sql:param value="${picture.id}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${sessionScope.userid}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${competistartdate}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competideadline}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competiwebsite}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competitermsnconds}" />
                </sql:update>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if> 
    </sql:transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do following things while working with MultipartData in JSP
1)Declare web.xml webapp version 3.0
2)Configure your controller with @MultiPartConfig
3)Move your Java Code in JSP to controller servlet
4)If you want to get that part in servlet do something like

```
Part mypart=request.getPart("Your Name Here")
mypart.getInputStream();
```

this way you can access part data from JSP to servlets.

If you are not using servlet 3.0 and above you can use apache commonsfileupload

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `getPart()`, but it was not working. I went to the  [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) and it said that i should use `getPart()` for the uploaded file but to use `request.getParameter()` for other input fields.
It worked!
I added this piece of code:

```
final String name = request.getParameter("name");
        final String startdate = request.getParameter("startdate");
        final String deadline = request.getParameter("deadline");
        final String website = request.getParameter("website");
        final String termsnconds = request.getParameter("termsnconds");
```

and this to the query to insert a new competition in `INSERT TO`

```
<c:forEach var="picture" items="${pictures.rows}">
                <c:set var="competiname" value="<%= name %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competistartdate" value="<%= startdate %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competideadline" value="<%= deadline %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competiwebsite" value="<%= website %>"></c:set>
                <c:set var="competitermsnconds" value="<%= termsnconds %>"></c:set>
                <sql:update>
                    INSERT INTO Competition (name, id_picture, id_sponsor, start_date, deadline, websiteURL, termsnconds) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
                    <sql:param value="${competiname}" />
                    <sql:param value="${picture.id}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${sessionScope.userid}" /> 
                    <sql:param value="${competistartdate}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competideadline}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competiwebsite}" />
                    <sql:param value="${competitermsnconds}" />
                </sql:update>   
            </c:forEach>
```

but i get a new problem, the input of `type="date"` return null... I'm going to check on that, and lets see if i can get something.